# ng-token-auth errors - preventing app from loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an AngularJs + Ruby on Rails app and I'm trying to integrate ng-token-auth, however I am getting the following warning and errors when my app loads, preventing the app from actually loading:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'validateOnPageLoad' of 
undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateOnPageLoad' of 
undefined
-
TypeError: Cannot read property 'proxyIf' of undefined
    at Object.apiUrl (ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:689)
    at ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:789
    at Object.invoke (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:4626)
    at request (ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:786)
    at processQueue (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:15758)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:15774
    at Scope.$eval (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:17026)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:16842)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:17065
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.self-5592af5….js?
    body=1:5825)
-
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:815
    at Object.invoke (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:4626)
    at responseError (ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:813)
    at processQueue (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:15758)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:15774
    at Scope.$eval (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:17026)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:16842)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:17065
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.self-5592af5….js?
    body=1:5825)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:6101
-
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateOnPageLoad' of undefined
    at Object.addScopeMethods (ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?
    body=1:168)
    at Object.initialize (ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:109)
    at ng-token-auth.self-50017ec….js?body=1:836
    at Object.invoke (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:4626)
    at angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:4434
    at forEach (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:322)
    at createInjector (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:4434)
    at doBootstrap (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:1711)
    at bootstrap (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:1732)
    at angularInit (angular.self-5592af5….js?body=1:1617)
```

here's my app index and auth config:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('MyApp', [
        'restangular',
        'ui.router',
        'templates',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ng-token-auth'
    ]).config(authConfig);

    authConfig.$inject = ['$authProvider'];

    /** @ngInject */
    function authConfig($authProvider) {
        $authProvider.configure({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/'
        });
    }
    })();
```

**UPDATE**
It seems that it either cannot find my config or getConfig does not exist:

```
addScopeMethods: function() {
                    return c.user = this.user,
                    c.authenticate = angular.bind(this, this.authenticate),
                    c.signOut = angular.bind(this, this.signOut),
                    c.destroyAccount = angular.bind(this, this.destroyAccount),
                    c.submitRegistration = angular.bind(this, this.submitRegistration),
                    c.submitLogin = angular.bind(this, this.submitLogin),
                    c.requestPasswordReset = angular.bind(this, this.requestPasswordReset),
                    c.updatePassword = angular.bind(this, this.updatePassword),
                    c.updateAccount = angular.bind(this, this.updateAccount),
                    this.getConfig().validateOnPageLoad ? this.validateUser({
                        config: this.getSavedConfig()
                    }) : void 0
                },
```

It fails in the above code on `this.getConfig().validateOnPageLoad` because getConfig() is undefined. `getSavedConfig()` returns the expected config, however...

---

I'm using devise on the back end, so my understanding is that I just need a minimal config like this to get started.

Please let me know what other info I can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I changed my config to:

```
function authConfig($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.configure([{
        default: {
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/'
        },
        user: {
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/'
        }
    }]);
}
```

in `getConfig` e was undefined, so `return t[this.getCurrentConfigName(e)]` was returning 'user', but I had no config named 'user', so 'undefined' was returned. Adding a named config fixed this issue since `t` here is an object with keys that are the names of your config values.